# "bees" -> "hive" in 5 letter changes or fewer

Tags: word, english, word-ladder

Example of "warm" -> "cold":

warm
worm
word
cord
cold

Notice that it's a real word each time. Can you get from "bees" -> "hive" in 5 letter changes or fewer?

Comment: Do we agree that your example has four changes - not five?

Comment: What counts as a "real word", exactly?

Comment: @Wolff imo that's a fact as the question is currently stated :) warm was changed but nothing changed into warm so warm itself does not count as a change.

Answer (score 51):

> Bees -> Beds -> Bids -> Bide -> Hide -> Hive

Comment: I wrote some code back in 2009 for solving this kind of puzzle (using A* on the SCOWL American wordlist) and this is the exact sequence it finds :)

Answer (score 17):

I find five solutions using only words in SOWPODS 2019, of which one has already been posted:

> BEES, BEDS, BEDE, BIDE, HIDE, HIVE
>  BEES, BEDS, BIDS, BIDE, HIDE, HIVE
>  BEES, DEES, DEVS, DIVS, DIVE, HIVE
>  BEES, DEES, DIES, DIVS, DIVE, HIVE
>  BEES, LEES, LEVS, LEVE, LIVE, HIVE

Of these, I expect the third to be the most popular with the Stack Exchange crowd...

Comment: I think you mean "the Stack Overflow crowd"...

Comment: @JL2210 Unless you assume the two overlap enough for the preference to be maintained in the SE crowd ;)

Answer (score 12):

With at least one obscure word:

> BEES
>  [BIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bies)
>  HIES
>  [HIVS](https://www.amnh.org/research/anthropology/news-events/histories-of-hivs)
>  HIVE

Comment: This is the only answer that meets the "five or fewer" rule. :) +1

Comment: @Duck Its 5 **changes**, so the first word is not counted as one, so the other answers meet that rule too. This one however does the 'fewer' part, which is awesome.

Comment: @EpicKip To me it looks like *five states* (words) with *four changes*, not five.

Comment: @andselisk That is exactly what I mean which is why I said `This one however does the 'fewer' part`. I was just quoting the question when I said `5 changes`

Comment: @EpicKip My bad, sorry for misunderstanding, you are correct.

Comment: I don't think abbreviations should count, almost any two to five letter combination is abbreviation that was already used somewhere.

Comment: I don't think "hivs" is a word. I tried searching for it on wiktionary, and it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Four changes using a couple of archaic/loan words and an acronym:

> bees → [BEVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_electric_vehicle) → [beve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beve) → [bive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bive) → hive

Comment: Hi. I don't think acronym can be a valid "word" for this type of puzzle.

Comment: @Luke Hi. HIV — human immunodeficiency virus — is also an acronym, and is used in [another answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/90517/63411). Since OP hasn't mentioned use of acronyms is prohibited, I assumed it's fine to use one.

Answer (score 2):

> BEES -> [BERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus_mauritiana) -> HERS -> HERE -> HIRE -> HIVE.

Answer (score 2):

1. bees
2. > bens (high mountains)
3. > bins (trash cans)
4. > bine (plant stem, esp. hops - yum!)
5. > hine (male Asian elephants without tusks; or an obsolete term for a servant)
6. hive

I only had to check number 5 for validity, I'm pleased to say.

Answer (score 1):

One archaic word :

> Bees -> Bets -> Bits -> Bite -> [Bive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bive) -> Hive

Answer (score 1):

5 changes, a little archaic...

> bees
>  rees
>  revs
>  reve
>  rive
>  hive

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has already been posted so trying to take an odd route:

> 0. bees
>  1. pees
>  2. pies
>  3. [hies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hie) (old English)
>  4. HIVs (human immunodeficiency viruses)
>  5. hive